# 5D Chess - Why is white king not in check in this position?

Tags: rules, chess-variants, check, illegal-move

Why cannot black rook on c5 in the bottom timeline capture the king on c5 in the top timeline? Why is the king not in check?

[image: chess position]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rook on the center board in the present is blocking the check. Even if it goes to the past, a copy stays on the board where it moved from. The rook on the center board isn't checking the king because it already moved to the past.

Comment: Oooh! Haha, awesome! Thanks! :D